# I want to print odd numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I want to print odd number using JavaScript below is code which is not working please suggest the correct code.

```html
<script>
    var myArray[];
    for(var i=1; i<10; i +=2){
        myArray.push(i);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: `var myArray = [];`

Comment: maybe `console.log(myArray)` or sth similar?

Comment: `myArray[];` is wrong. `myArray = [];`

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `var myArray = []` and then print the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray=new Array();
        for(var i=1; i<10; i +=2){
            myArray.push(i);
        }
console.log(myArray)
```